# Unable to abort rebase using git

Tags: git, github, rebase

I started rebasing but had to end it. However, whenever i type `git rebase --abort` i get the following:

```
Elaines-MacBook-Pro:team byrne$ git rebase --abort
No rebase in progress?
Elaines-MacBook-Pro:team byrne$
```

Any idea how to get out of this? I have tried various methods but nothing seems to get working. There's a lot of conflict files and hence have to abort.

git status:

```
Elaines-MacBook-Pro:team byrne$ git status
On branch newrebased
Your branch and 'origin/newrebased' have diverged,
and have 3 and 23 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

    modified:   client/app/post.html

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   client/app/app.js
    both modified:   client/app/post.controller.js

Elaine-MacBook-Pro:team byrne$
```

Update: I did `git reset --mixed` and it seems to have gone the trick. However, I ran into another issue.

```
Elaines-MacBook-Pro:team byrne$ git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    client/app/services/constants.development.js
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
Elaines-MacBook-Pro:team byrne$ git stash
No local changes to save
Elaines-MacBook-Pro:team byrne$
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: What do you get for `git status`?

Comment: This is what I get when I go `git status`: `On branch newrebased
Your branch and 'origin/newrebased' have diverged,
and have 3 and 23 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

 modified:   client/app/post.html

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

 both modified:   client/app/app.js
 both modified:   client/app/post.controller.js
Elaines-MacBook-Pro:team byrne$`

Comment: I tried `git stash` too but got this:
`client/app/app.js: needs merge` etc

Comment: *I started rebasing but had to end it* Will you please elaborate this part in your question (what git commands did you run)?

Comment: I started with `git rebase master` and then tried resolving the conflicts. However, i run into issues so tried `git rebase --abort` but I was shown `No rebase in progress?`.

Comment: Will you please also add the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate master HEAD ORIG_HEAD`?

Comment: I used `git reset --mixed` and seems to have disappear. However, I ran into another issue. Check the updated question please.

Comment: I don't think that we can help you to fix the issue as you are on your way of deviating from the original problem and, maybe, breaking something

Comment: yeah! Let me see what I can do with my other team who has knowledge of what's happening. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Suppose you end up doing "rm -rf *" and then saying "Now the previous problem is gone, but now I have another one"